# how to create directory structure in readme.md in VS Code

Tags: markdown, readme

Is there any easiest way to create project directory structure in readme.md file in VS Code or CMD?
for example :
I have following project directory structure and want to put these folder structure to readme file.

[image]

In Readme.md

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is simple way to create folder/directory structure into Readme.md file.

1. Open the VS code and select your project folder, in my example it is "Test"
2. Open the Terminal and run cmd `"tree"`, it will display the directory structure into terminal, where you can copy the structure and add into your Readme.md.

[image]

If you want to display directory structures along with file , run
the `tree /F` the files name will included.

[image]